# Laravel 5.4.22 PHP - Trying to just hook up this route to simply post the data to the page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

So Im currently building a simple email registry, and my issue is that I am recieving a MethodNotAllowedHttpException for posting.

Here is my Register.php controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Register extends Controller
{
    public function validateCredentials()
    {
      $email = Input::post('emailInput');
      return "Email: " . $email;
  }
}
```

Im simply just running these routes currently

```
Route::get('/index', function(){
    return view('index');
});
Route::post('/index', 'Register@validateCredentials');
```

Im assuming the bulk of my issue is located inside of my form itself:

```
<form method="post">
    @CSRF
    <input type="email"
           placeholder="Your email"
           name="emailInput"
           class="ct"/>
    <input type="submit"
           value="Sign Up"
           name="submitInput"
           class="bbg vtm"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the action route to your form?<form action="{{ url('/index') }}" method="post">

Comment: just try it in small letters `@csrf`

Comment: I've given both of these tries, and neither seemed to work for me.

I have an assumption - Im posting from localhost - do I need this to be on a server to do any form of actions?

All this action needs to do is collect the email and print it out - I have decent database knowledge and collecting/posting data, I'm just new to Laravel specifically so the requirements are a bit interesting

Comment: I tried this

Route::post('/index', 'SendEmail@validateCredentials')->name('emailInput');

And renamed my register.php controller to SendEmail.php to try and see if it was a safe-word issue. Same error

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller method to:

```
public function validateCredentials(Request $request)
{
  $email = $request->get('emailInput');
  return "Email: " . $email;
}
```

maybe it helps you

Comment: its `$request->input(...)`